# TimeStamp::getTimeZoneOffset returns the same offset for STD and DST?

Tags: c++11, timezone-offset, occi

I'm getting the time zone offset of a `TIMESTAMP` column using [`oracle::occi::Timestamp::getTimeZoneOffset` method](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNCPP/reference033.htm#LNCPP21860), but got the same results when retrieving a timestamp value in summer time (`2020-09-30`) than when retrieving other value which is in standard time (`2020-03-01`).

The environment is as follow:

- Oracle XE 11G R2
- Time Zone = `Europe/Madrid` (UTC offset: STD=+01:00; DST=+02:00)
- Temp table with one row and two columns:

  ```sql
  CREATE TABLE TEST_TZ_OFFSET
  AS 
  SELECT TIMESTAMP '2020-09-30 00:00:00.000000' AS DST,
         TIMESTAMP '2020-03-01 00:00:00.000000' AS STD
  FROM DUAL
  ```
- Oracle Instant Client for Linux x86-64 Version 12.2.0.1.0

When the column in DST is fetched it works as expected (7200 seconds = +02:00), but when STD column is fetched **it has the same offset as in DST** when it is suppose to be 3600 seconds (+01:00)

```cpp
long getGMTOffset(oracle::occi::Connection *conn, const std::string &columnName) {
    oracle::occi::Timestamp timestamp;
    oracle::occi::Statement *stmt;
    int tzhour = 0, tzminute = 0;

    try {
        std::string query = "SELECT " + columnName + " FROM TEST_TZ_OFFSET";
        stmt = conn->createStatement();
        stmt->setSQL(query);
        oracle::occi::ResultSet *rs = stmt->executeQuery();

        if (rs->next()) {
            timestamp = rs->getTimestamp(1);
        }
        
        stmt->closeResultSet(rs);
        conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    } catch (const std::exception &e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << "\n";
        conn->terminateStatement(stmt);
    }

    timestamp.getTimeZoneOffset(tzhour, tzminute);
    return (tzhour * 60 + tzminute) * 60;
}

std::cout << "GMT Offset of STD column = " << getGMTOffset(connection, "STD") << "\n";
std::cout << "GMT Offset of DST column = " << getGMTOffset(connection, "DST") << "\n";
```

Output:

```
GMT Offset of STD column = 7200
GMT Offset of DST column = 7200
```

Is this the expected behaviour?

Comment: It may just be giving you back the current offset, rather than the offset at that timestamp.  Does it work if you use a `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE` column as a source instead?  Try something like `TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2020-09-30 00:00:00.000000') AS DST`, etc...

Comment: [Here's it working in pure SQL statements](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=208783b8823adc50d400fbe494a2b699).  I don't have a good OCCI test harness available at the moment.

Comment: Also - I hope that string concatenation in your example is just for testing.  It would be a potential source for a SQL Injection attack in the real world.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, I've tried with `TIMESTAMP_WITH_TIMEZONE` and it works the same way. It seems that `oracle::occi::ResultSet::getTimestamp` always set the current offset, no matter what value of timestamp is retrieving.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint, also thanks for your working example in pure SQL, but unfortunately I cannot add the calculated column to the query.

And yes, my example is just for testing, so there is no risk of SQL injection.

Comment: If `oracle::occi::ResultSet::getTimestamp` is always returning the *current* offset instead of the offset applicable at that timestamp, that sounds like a bug to me.  You'll probably have to go through Oracle Support to get it investigated properly, though you could also try the forum at https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/call_interface. Good luck!

Comment: I've asked in the community forum

https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4497875/oracle-occi-resultset-gettimestamp-always-returns-the-current-time-offset

Comment: Feel free to post an answer here when you learn something either way.  Thanks!